# using Array.map and filter on an array of objects, trying to remove items that hold values that are NaN

Tags: javascript

As stated in title, i'm trying to remove items that hold values that are NaN in an array of objects.

```
distanceMatrix = [{
    'Av. Vieira Souto, 168 - Ipanema, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 22420-004, Brazil': 'ZERO_RESULTS'
},
{
    'Rynek Główny 12, 33-332 Kraków, Poland': 1540493
},
{
    '27 Derb Lferrane, Marrakech 40000, Morocco': 2539727
},
{
    'R. Roberto Símonsen, 122 - Sé, São Paulo - SP, 01017-020, Brazil': 'ZERO_RESULTS'
}]
```

I am trying to run this function without avail:

```
distanceMatrix.map((location, index)=>{
    Object.values(location)
    .filter((item)=>{return !isNaN(item[0]) ? item[0] : null});
});
```

I am looking to reshape `distanceMatrix` to have items that hold only number values.
Would be happy to know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: please add the data before and after the filtering.

Comment: Your data is not in correct format, not a valid object

Comment: @CodeManiac you're saying that `{ 'Av. Vieira Souto, 168 - Ipanema, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 22420-004, Brazil': 'ZERO_RESULTS' }` this is not a valid object? why? quote instead of double quote?

Comment: @CodeManiac the array contains valid objects.

Comment: @clusterBuddy sorry my bad i didn't realized your key is so long.yeah it's a valid one

Comment: do you have control over the way those objects are structured? Usually the keys of an object are known, and used to look up the unknown value. Like this: `{
    address: 'Rynek Główny 12, 33-332 Kraków, Poland', population: 1540493
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what your sample of data shown, the `objects` on your array consist only of a pair of `key` and `value`. So `Object.values()` will return an array with only one `value`. You can check if that value is a valid number, and if not, filter the whole object out:

```js
const distanceMatrix = [
  {'Av. Vieira Souto, 168 - Ipanema, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 22420-004, Brazil': 'ZERO_RESULTS'},
  {'Rynek Główny 12, 33-332 Kraków, Poland': 1540493},
  {'27 Derb Lferrane, Marrakech 40000, Morocco': 2539727},
  {'R. Roberto Símonsen, 122 - Sé, São Paulo - SP, 01017-020, Brazil': 'ZERO_RESULTS'}
];

let res = distanceMatrix.filter(o => !isNaN(+Object.values(o)[0]));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

On the previous example, we use **[Unary Plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())** to coerces the only value of the array returned by `Object.values()` to a number, then we check if the result of the casting is a number or not with **[isNan()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)**.

Comment: so this is interesting @shidersz, `distanceMatrix` is not being runover by `filter()`, only when pointed to a new memory location. Care to explain? I thought filter changes the array itself in the same memory location.

Comment: @clusterBuddy filter doesn't modify the array, it creates a modified copy of it.

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution to remove objects that contain a value which is not a number would be a filter:

```
const filteredDistanceMatrix = distanceMatrix.filter(location => {
    const value = Object.values(location)[0]
    return !isNaN(value)
})
```

The `filter` returns a copy of `distanceMatrix` without the objects containing a NaN value.

Comment: This: https://gist.github.com/PierreTurnbull/7764463cd00519d9e86eb3143bff795a will give you the right result

Comment: The predicate passed to `.filter()` is expected to return a `Boolean`

Comment: You need to capture the result, ie, `var thing = distanceMatrix.filter(...)` otherwise it's pointless.

Answer (score 1):

this can use for any length key-value pair inner object

```
distanceMatrix.map(location => Object.keys(location).reduce((acc, k) => { acc[k] = !isNaN(location[k]) ? location[k] : null; return acc },{}))
```

Answer (score 0):

your current code outputs

```
[
    [], 
    [1540493], 
    [2539727], 
    []
]
```

I'm guessing you want to then reduce this array to a list of good values

```
const data = [
  { 'Av. Vieira Souto, 168 - Ipanema, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 22420-004, Brazil': 'ZERO_RESULTS' },
  { 'Rynek Główny 12, 33-332 Kraków, Poland': 1540493 },
  { '27 Derb Lferrane, Marrakech 40000, Morocco': 2539727 },
  { 'R. Roberto Símonsen, 122 - Sé, São Paulo - SP, 01017-020, Brazil': 'ZERO_RESULTS' }
]

const out =[];
data.forEach(loc => {
    const results = Object.values(loc).filter(l => !isNaN(l));
    out.push(...results);
});
// [1540493, 2539727]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```js
distanceMatrix = [
{ 'Av. Vieira Souto, 168 - Ipanema, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 22420-004, Brazil': 'ZERO_RESULTS' },
  { 'Rynek Główny 12, 33-332 Kraków, Poland': 1540493 },
  { '27 Derb Lferrane, Marrakech 40000, Morocco': 2539727 },
  { 'R. Roberto Símonsen, 122 - Sé, São Paulo - SP, 01017-020, Brazil': 'ZERO_RESULTS' }
]

var result = distanceMatrix.filter((item)=>{
 var itemValue = parseInt(Object.values(item)[0]);
  return !isNaN(itemValue);
});

console.log(result);
```